# QGIS crashes when updating / deleting / starting the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins

My QGIS (2.18) crashes when updating / deleting / starting / activating / deactivating the Semi-Automatic Classification Plug-in without any log-massage.

QGIS startup massage is:

> Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin: Please, restart QGIS for
>   executing the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin. Possible missing
>   dependencies.

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using? A [new version](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/) (5.2.2) was uploaded on the 24th November 2016 (yesterday!). Perhaps try that? It seems to work fine on my QGIS 2.18.0 for Windows 7 64-bit.